# Gridview's Boundfield Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridvew on my form with some fields . I added two fields to my gridview cause i wanted to use the data in them in my behind code and i fetch them in behind code, but the thing is i don't want those columns to be visible in gridview, so i tried to set their visible attribute 'False' but that didn't work, i didnt have access to their data. how can it be achieved?

```
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Service_Id" HeaderText="Service_Id"   SortExpression="Service_Id" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Gray"
            Visible="true">
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Gray"></HeaderStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserId" HeaderText="UserID" SortExpression="UserId" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Gray"
            Visible="true">
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Gray"></HeaderStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
```

And this is my page's behind code :

```
    Button Button1 = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow grdRow = (GridViewRow)Button1.Parent.Parent;
        HiddenFieldServiceID.Value = grdRow.Cells[0].Text;
        HiddenFieldUserID.Value = grdRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `BoundField` for this. Use the [DataKeyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx) property instead.
The values can then be fetched using `DataKeys[rowIndex]`

ASPX:

```
DataKeyNames="Service_Id, UserId";
```

Code:

```
var Service_Id = (int)gv.DataKeys[rowIndex]["Service_Id"];
var UserId = (int)gv.DataKeys[rowIndex]["UserId"];
```